# How do I sleep for a millisecond in bash or ksh

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, shell-scripting, ksh

sleep is a very popular command and we can start sleep from 1 second:

```
# wait one second please 
sleep 1
```

but what the alternative if I need to wait only 0.1 second or between 0.1 to 1 second ?

- remark: on linux or OS X **`sleep 0.XXX`** works fine , but on solaris **`sleep 0.1`** or **`sleep 0.01`** - illegal syntax

Comment: Can I ask why you want to sleep for 1ms?

Comment: Yes of course , in my bash script I add "sleep 1" , in some lines , but script run very slowly , so after some conclusion I calculate that sleep 0.1 also bring good results and more faster About the delay , I need delay in order to solve the ssh problem in my bash script , I perform paralel ssh login to some machines by expect and without delay its will not work , As you know from my question the delay should fit both Linux and Solaris

Comment: Whatever solution you choose, keep in mind that a shell script won't be very accurate in terms of timing.

Comment: How about doing something that  takes a very short time to execute, but does nothing.. like `echo "" >/dev/null`

Comment: Good idea but how msec this command take? , I need 0.1 msec , not less then that -:)

Comment: Support for decimal arguments in Solaris sleep was added in Solaris 11.  For older OS'es try installing GNU coreutils.

Comment: Beware! In macOS Sierra (at least the initial 10.12 release), ksh's built-in sleep does not work correctly for values ≤ 30. $ time sleep 5 real 0m0.00s user 0m0.00s sys 0m0.00s $ time sleep 30 real 0m0.00s user 0m0.00s sys 0m0.00s $ time sleep 31 real 0m31.01s user 0m0.00s sys 0m0.00s

Comment: these solutions seem overly complex, is that not a simpler way to do this? `sleep -ms 50`?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Bash has a "loadable" sleep which supports fractional seconds, and eliminates overheads of an external command:

```
$ cd bash-3.2.48/examples/loadables
$ make sleep && mv sleep sleep.so
$ enable -f sleep.so sleep
```

Then:

```
$ which sleep
/usr/bin/sleep
$ builtin sleep
sleep: usage: sleep seconds[.fraction]
$ time (for f in `seq 1 10`; do builtin sleep 0.1; done)
real    0m1.000s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s
```

The downside is that the loadables may not be provided with your `bash` binary, so you would need to compile them yourself as shown (though on Solaris it would not necessarily be as simple as above).

**As of `bash-4.4`** (September 2016) all the loadables are now built and installed by default on platforms that support it, though they are built as separate shared-object files, and without a `.so` suffix. Unless your distro/OS has done something creative (sadly RHEL/CentOS 8 build `bash-4.4` with loadable extensions *deliberately* removed), you should be able to do instead:

```
[ -z "$BASH_LOADABLES_PATH" ] &&
  BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=$(pkg-config bash --variable=loadablesdir 2>/dev/null)  
enable -f sleep sleep
```

(The man page implies `BASH_LOADABLES_PATH` is set automatically, I find this is not the case in the official distribution as of 4.4.12. If and when it is set correctly you need only `enable -f filename commandname` as required.)

If that's not suitable, the next easiest thing to do is build or obtain `sleep` from GNU coreutils, this supports the required feature. The POSIX [`sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html) command is minimal, older Solaris versions implemented only that. [Solaris 11 `sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/sleep-1.html#scrolltoc) *does* support fractional seconds.

As a last resort you could use `perl` (or any other scripting that you have to hand) with the caveat that initialising the interpreter may be comparable to the intended sleep time:

```
$ perl -e "select(undef,undef,undef,0.1);"
$ echo "after 100" | tclsh
```

Comment: Ah, since you're using `expect` you can probably just use "`after N`", where N is milliseconds, directly in your script.

Comment: use `usleep` like @Luis Vazquez and @sebix write

Comment: Apple MacOS has BSD sleep, which also supports fractional seconds

Answer (score 174):

The documentation for the [`sleep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html) command from **coreutils** says:

> Historical implementations of sleep have required that number be an
>   integer, and only accepted a single argument without a suffix.
>   However, GNU sleep accepts arbitrary floating point numbers. See
>   [Floating point](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Floating-point.html).

Hence you can use `sleep 0.1`, `sleep 1.0e-1` and similar arguments.

Comment: see my remark about SOLARIS OS

Comment: Did you mix up *is* and *isn't*?

Comment: see my update in my quastion

Comment: Yael, I think there're still one too many negatives in your question; are you sure you mean "not illegal syntax"?

Comment: for example - I run on solaris 10 this: # sleep 0.1 sleep: bad character in argument  , about linux  sleep 0.1 works fine

Comment: Note: The built-in Bash command `sleep` is different from the external / separate binary `sleep`, which is usually installed in `/bin/sleep` or `/usr/bin/sleep`.  By default, Bash will use the built-in, so use `"$(which sleep)"` to be very clear about using external binary.

Comment: My Debian/Ubuntu based NodeJs image in CodeSandbox has `sleep (GNU coreutils) 8.30` and supports this use of fractional seconds.

Answer (score 79):

Sleep accepts decimal numbers so you can break it down this like:

1/2 of a second

```
 sleep 0.5
```

1/100 of a second

```
sleep 0.01
```

So for a millisecond you would want

```
sleep 0.001
```

Comment: You can also drop the leading zero before the decimal point. eg. `sleep .5`

Comment: Except for http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52352.html

Comment: Talk about everyone else overcomplicating it...

Comment: @MikeCauser leading zeros much more readable and signal intent to the reader of the code later. also better when you actually do math.

Answer (score 13):

Try this to determine accuracy:

```
    time sleep 0.5      # 500 milliseconds (1/2 of a second)
    time sleep 0.001    # 1 millisecond (1/1000 of a second)
    time sleep 1.0      # 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
```

Combination of [mr.spuratic's solution](https://serverfault.com/a/469259) and [coles's solution](https://serverfault.com/a/469252).

Answer (score 13):

You may simply use `usleep`. It takes microseconds (= 1e-6 seconds) as parameter, so to sleep 1 millisecond you would enter:

```
usleep 1000
```

Comment: `$ usleep`
`No command 'usleep' found, did you mean:`
`Command 'sleep' from package 'coreutils' (main)`
`usleep: command not found`

Comment: No, i mean `usleep` part of the `initscripts` package which is standard at least in all the Red Hat derived distributions; including at least RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, Mageia/Mandriva and SuSE.
Here an example:
``
``

Comment: Here is a sample ilustration running in CentOS 7:
```
$ which usleep
/usr/bin/usleep
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/usleep
initscripts-9.49.37-1.el7_3.1.x86_64
```
To summarize: 
- `sleep` (from **coreutils**) works with seconds
- `usleep` (from **initscripts**) works with micro-seconds

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (no shell usleep on Solaris) so I wrote my own thus:

```
  #include "stdio.h"
  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     if(argc == 2) { usleep(atoi(argv[1])); }
     return 0;
}
```

Doesn't check arguments - I'd recommend a properly written one if you wanted to keep it but that (gcc usleep.c -o usleep) will get you out of a hole.

Comment: You could *at least* change that bare `usleep()` call to `if(argc == 1) { usleep(atoi(argv[1])); }` to avoid indexing outside of the bounds of the array, which can lead to any number of unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @aCVn It's actually `if (argc == 2)  { usleep(atoi(argv[1])); }` ...

Comment: Also note that `usleep` unit is μs, so to wait 1 second, you need to provide a 1000000 argument.

Comment: @RingØ Right. Stupid mistake, good catch.

Comment: `atoi()` is a horrible choice to convert a string to an `int`.  What does `atoi( "STRING" )` return? `atoi()` has no way to return any error.

Answer (score 0):

I like the usleep idea, but I can't make a comment under it.
Since this helped me out, I hope my suggestion can improve the usleep idea.

https://github.com/fedora-sysv/initscripts/blob/3c3fe4a4d1b2a1113ed302df3ac9866ded51b01b/src/usleep.c is the actual source code for usleep.c on the redhat ecosystem.

Try to compile that in your Solaris. You'd probably need https://www.opencsw.org/packages/libpopt0/.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX specification for [`sleep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html) only accepts an integral argument -- so no fractions of a second.  GNU's [coreutils `sleep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html) adds support for real numbers, suffixes, even scientific notation and `inf`inity as **GNU extensions**. But if you're on embedded system with `busybox` or just don't have coreutils, then you're out of luck unless you have perl.

```perl
perl -e 'select(undef, undef, undef, 0.1);'
```