# Does the bash usleep block? Or will it yield to other threads?

Tags: bash, block

I understand there is a usleep command in bash. Is this a "busy" or "blocking" sleep? Or will this yield time to other processes?

Answer (score 4):

This probably don't really belong on Server Fault (though I'm not sure which site it would belong on), but here's an answer anyway:

The bash shell does not have a builtin `usleep` command (nor does it have a builtin `sleep` command).  `sleep` is a standard *program* on Unix systems and is available regardless of which shell you're running.  `usleep` appears to be a program that was written by people at RedHat and might only be present in RedHat-related distributions (RHEL and derivatives; Fedora).  It doesn't appear to be available in Debian.

In any case, `sleep` and `usleep` use the standard `sleep()` and `usleep()` system calls, which pause program execution for the specified amount of time[0] (making them "blocking"), and use no CPU time during their sleep (making them *not* "busy").

[0] The amount of time isn't actually guaranteed to be precisely what was requested, because of the way the kernel scheduler works.  The usual guarantee is that it will sleep for *at least* the requested time.  This isn't an issue for integer `sleep()` durations, because the variance will be much less than a second, but `usleep()` durations (and fractional `sleep()` durations) might not end up being exact.

Comment: I suspect [unix.se] would be the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `usleep` command in bash. `usleep: command not found` on bash 4.3.11 and nothing like that mentioned in the [changelog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) ...

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/469247/how-do-i-sleep-for-a-millisecond-in-bash-or-ksh/704338#704338?newreg=3f247116a41343b7bd7b134da953b08d

Comment: And it works - seems to yield - not block.

Comment: Then this is not a bash builtin but an external utility. What does `which usleep` say? Why on earth should it block anyway?

Comment: `usleep` appears to be a RH/Fedora utility that only exists in these distributions as part of the `initscripts` package.